# Record Video from Browser using Webcam and Microfone inputs

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, browser, client-side

I need to record a video through user browser using input from camera and microphone and send to my server. Since html5 still doesn't make that magic happen, I'm looking for flash solutions.

Do I really need some flash media server to do that, or can I do a POST request?

I want to get both inputs(webcam and microphone), put them in a .flv and send to my server.

I've seen some implementations using bytearrays to record and send, audio and video separated. The problem is that it generates a series of synchronization problems when you try to compose them in a single file.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still looking for a solution check out:

http://framebase.io

They have an embed-able recording widget that can transcode the videos automatically. I'd check out the docs, but on success, you can run an API call to check the status of transcoding and download it to your server or you can just use your own S3 bucket.